# I cannot see the columns of the 16x16 grid in the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to build a 16x16 grid however the makeColumns function does not seem to work and I can only see the divs from the function makeRows in the DOM. Here is my code. (in my HTML body I have only )

```
const container = document.querySelector("#container");
const gridRows = document.querySelectorAll(".rows");
const gridCells = document.querySelectorAll(".cells");

function makeGrid() {
   makeRows(16);
   makeColumns(256);
};

console.log(makeGrid())

function makeRows(numberOfRows) {
    for(let i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
        let row = document.createElement("div");
        row.classList.add("rows");
        container.appendChild(row);
    };
};


function makeColumns(numberOfCells){
    for(let j = 0; j < gridRows.length; j++){
        for(let k = 0; k < numberOfCells; k++){
            let cell = document.createElement("div");
            cell.classList.add("cells");
            gridRows[k].appendChild(cell);
        
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: `gridRows` is at the moment of the call still empty. you need to update your variable after you created new `.rows`

Comment: @Sysix I do not understand why gridRows is empty and how shall I update it

Comment: What @Sysix is saying is that: you are defining `gridRows` at document load. That means, it's empty when you are trying to add columns. You need to update the  `gridRows`  constant (or use `let` or `var` since it's not really a constant) AFTER you've created them. You can update that after the `for` in the `makeRows` function. Basically create an empty var for `gridRows` where the constant is currently defined, and then put your `document.query.....` for `gridRows` in the `makeRows` function.

Comment: @disinfor this caused another issue now. In my console, when I console.log the makeColumns function I receive an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined
    at makeColumns". The undefined is the gridRows[k] which is inside the makeRows function

Comment: I was only offering a place to start, I didn't test my comment.